# Reconstructing a graph from the multiset of degrees

Tags: graph-theory

Suppose $G, H$ are finite, simple, undirected graphs and there is a bijection between the vertex sets $\varphi:V(G) \to V(H)$ such that for all $v\in V$ we have $$\text{deg}_G(v) = \deg_H(\varphi(v)).$$

Does this imply that $G\cong H$? In case the answer is positive, does it remain so if we consider infinite graphs?

Comment: Of course not.  Otherwise, all $k$-regular graphs with the same number of vertices would be isomorphic.  $K_{3,3}$ and the triangular prism is a concrete counterexample.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, consider the [Petersen graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Petersen_graph) and another with no star in the middle but just a simple pentagon. The former has no 4-cycle, but the latter has one.

Comment: There is a saying: Never conjecture anything in graph theory before trying the Petersen graph! :)

Comment: Excellent one! Will keep it in mind.

Answer (score 4):

If the answer were yes for finite graphs, the Graph Isomorphism computational problem would be trivially in $P$.  This is not known.  In fact, Babai recently showed with quite a bit of effort that it is in pseudo-polynomial time, and this was a major breakthrough.